# Does TinyMCE PowerPaste support pasting images from a browser as Base64

Tags: tinymce, clipboard

From the TinyMCE PowerPaste plugin [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/powerpaste/) :

> If you configure PowerPaste to allow local images (see the
>   powerpaste_allow_local_images setting below) then images pasted from
>   Microsoft Word **and other sources** will appear in TinyMCE as Base64
>   encoded images.

It's not clear what *and other sources* means. Does it include things copied over from a browser?

- From https://stackoverflow.com/a/39842881/329660 I assume that an image pasted as part of a *chunk of HTML* can't be pasted as binary data in TinyMCE.
- *But* if the user right clicks the image and "**copy image**" from their browser, is PowerPaste supposed to paste the full Base64 data in the editor (granted that the browser put the data in the correct format in the clipboard in the first place, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

The "other sources" for this is typically just Excel.  Word and Excel are the two office products that consistently place image binaries into the clipboard in RTF format that PowerPaste can extract.

If another office product did the same PowerPaste would see that and grab it as well but at present I don't know of another office product that does exactly what Word and Excel do with images.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I was not necessarily thinking about other Office products but browsers.  Do you confirm that this PowerPaste "Base64" behavior does not hold when copy/pasting an image from IE or Firefox, for instance?

Comment: It all depends on what is placed into the clipboard which can be dependent on each browser.  The home page of TinyMCE has a working copy of PowerPaste running so you can test any specific scenario on that page.